Adjust default value in Blazor model
In my app I have a BaseEntity model that is inherited by all other models, it looks like this.
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; set; }
}

In a given model I'm doing something like this.
public class TagVariant : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag? Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : BaseEntity
{
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<TagVariant> Variants { get; set; } = new List<TagVariant>();
}

My controller looks like this.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<Tag>>> CreateTag(Tag tag)
{
    //temp force to be false
    tag.IsDeleted = false;

    _dataContext.Tags.Add(tag);
    await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(tag);
}

As you can see I'm having to manually tell the submission to change isDeleted to be false.  I have it set in the model, so why am I having to manually set it?
Thanks!

You're missing an important detail.  Where is the parameter "tag" coming from?

I updated the post to include more detail.  Thanks for the reply!

My test needn't set false again.
